# Code analysis warning when declaring an event in an interface

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, code-analysis

Why is this declaration of an event in the following interface complaining in the code analyzer with a CA1009? In the implementation it does indeed seem to follow the standard conventions of event declaration.

```
using System;

namespace Client.Wpf.Utilities.MessageSubscription
{
    public interface ITrigger<TMessageType>
    {
        event EventHandler<TMessageType> Fire;
    }
}
```

**CA1009    Declare event handlers correctly**

Declare the second parameter of 'EventHandler' as an EventArgs, or an instance of a type that extends EventArgs, named 'e'.

ITrigger.cs 7

And the implementation:

```
using System;
//using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging;

namespace Client.Wpf.Utilities.MessageSubscription
{
    public class MvvmMessageTrigger<TMessageType> : ITrigger<TMessageType>
    {
        public MvvmMessageTrigger()
        {
            //Messenger.Default.Register<TMessageType>(this, InvokeSubscribers);
        }

        public event EventHandler<TMessageType> Fire;

        private void InvokeSubscribers(TMessageType messageType)
        {
            if (null != Fire)
            {
                Fire(this, messageType);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the declaration of TMessageType ?

Comment: In the two places it is used just a plain old class, nothing special. public class Whatever { public string SomeProperty { get; set; } }

Comment: So it isn't derived from EventArgs, like all .NET event data arguments are?  Which is what the message is complaining about.  You can ignore it if you want to, it merely confuses whatever programmer is going to write an event handler for the event.

Comment: might help.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182133(VS.100).aspx

Comment: @HansPassant yes that is it, please post as answer. Still not changing it though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty self evident:

Declare the second parameter of 'EventHandler' as an EventArgs, or an instance of a type that extends EventArgs, named 'e'.

In my example above TMessageType was not inheriting from EventArgs, and thus the warning.